# Slack API - Post message via user email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack-api, slack

I need to send a message to slack user but have only the email address of the user.

Does Slack API provide such functionality?

Any idea/workaround is really appreciated!

Edit:
I need to send a slack message from jenkins, according to the build state. Jenkins Slack Plugin does not provide such functionality as far as I am aware, so I'm trying to do that directly calling Slack API from jenkins shell.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to implement with the Slack API.

1. Call [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) to get all users including their email
   addresses.
2. Find the correct Slack user by matching the email address.
3. Call [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) to send a Slack message to the user. Use the Slack user ID as channel name to send a direct message to the user.

Comment: That is the way I have achieved in my implementation. I am curious maybe there is another smart way to do so. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been 5 years.... But for future seekers like myself - there is a method [users.lookupByEmail](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail), very handy if only one up to few users needed from the organization.